# ScrollMagic: Stick element to bottom of sticky/fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I try to use "setPin" method of scrollmagic to make an element sticky at a certain moment. 
I made a screencast to show you my problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7r1xu1gdgm22is8/stick.mov?dl=0
As you can see i am already manipulating the header section with scrollmagic (resizing the logo). When the blue bar reaches the sticked header section, i want it to be sticked too so the blue bar is always visible. Hope it is clear what i mean?! :)
by default scrollmagics setpin method triggers when element reaches the viewport center. but i want the trigger when element "touches" the bottom border of my sticked header.
This is my code so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
    var introTl = new TimelineLite();
    introTl.to(logoimg, 1, {width: 100, autoRound:false});
    var introScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({duration: 200}).setTween(introTl).addTo(controller);
    var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#actionbar"
    })
    .setPin("#actionbar")
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `triggerHook` and `triggerElement` options before or after `duration: 200`

`triggerHook` is the position on the screen that triggers the pin. It ranges from 0 (the top of the screen) to 1 (the bottom of the screen)

`triggerElemeent` identifies the trigger

something along the lines of

```
var introScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: '#img_above_blue_bar', triggerHook: 0, duration: 200}).setTween(introTl).addTo(controller);
```

should be helpful.